# Какая технология может преобразовать текст данным образом?

Tags: java, текст

Имеется большое количество методов, которые надо переписать определённым образом.
Для примера, вот исходный метод:

```
/**
 * Finds all
 * @param id    the id
 * @param codes list of codes
 * @return entities
*/
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Entity> get(@QueryParam("id") Integer id, @QueryParam("barcodes") List<Long> codes) {
  return entityBean.findByIdAndCodes(id, codes);
}
```

Он должен быть переписан таким образом:

```
/**
 * Finds all
 * @param id    the id
 * @param codes list of codes
 * @return entities
*/
@RequestLine("GET " + PATH + "get")
List<Entity> get(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("codes") List<Long> codes);
```

То есть переписывание кода должно идти по следующему сценарию:

- Тело метода заменяется символом `;`.
- У метода уходит модификатор доступа.
- Уходят аннотации `@GET`, `@Path` и `@Produces`.
- Комментарий переносится без изменений.
- Над методом формируется строка такого вида: `@RequestLine("[аннотация @GET без символа @]" + PATH + "[содержимое аннотации @Path без первого символа /]")`.
- Аннотации параметров метода меняются с `@QueryParam` на `@Param`.

Возвращаемый тип, количество параметров и название могут быть разными в разных методах. Также вместо аннотации `@GET` может быть `@POST` или `@DELETE`.

Какая технология позволит мне выполнить такое преобразование кода наиболее эффективно?

Comment: Я бы сделал шапку, к которой добавлял найденные строки. А исходный текст разбил бы на массив строк, находил строку с содержанием List<Entity>, удалял из неё public и добавлял к шапке. Это буквально строк 10 кода. Ну ещё заменить некоторые слова, через replace

Comment: В чем конкретно вопрос как написать реализацию вашей новой аннотации @RequestLine?
Или как отрефакторить весь проект перейдя на новую аннотацию "одной кнопкой"?

Comment: @ArtyMorris я сейчас допишу это в вопрос, но сигнатуры методов могут отличаться.

Comment: @JVic нет, вопрос в том, как автоматически переписать метод. Мне это нужно, потому что мне надо переписать большое количество похожих методов, и мне лень это делать руками.

Comment: Java Instrumentation API:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для решения проблемы я использовал `Live template` - это инструмент в `IDEA`, который позволяет создавать удобные шаблоны для преобразования / формирования кода.

Сам шаблон выглядел вот так:

```
$METHOD$
```

Код шаблона *(для преобразования текста я использовал скрипт, написанный на `Groovy`)*:

```
groovyScript("D:\\method.groovy", clipboard())
```

`groovyScript()` здесь служит для указания скрипта, который будет использоваться для преобразования текста *(первый аргумент - сам скрипт или путь к файлу со скриптом, второй аргумент - текстовая переменная, передающаяся в скрипт)*. `clipboard()` - это содержимое буфера обмена.

Сам скрипт:

```
def result = '';

def commentMatcher = _1 =~ "(/\\*{2}[^/]*\\*/)";
if (commentMatcher.find()) result = commentMatcher[0][0];

result += '\r\n@RequestLine("';
def httpMethodMatcher = _1 =~ "@(GET|POST|DELETE)";
if (httpMethodMatcher.find()) {
    result += httpMethodMatcher[0][1];
    result += ' " + PATH + ';
}

def isSignatureMatcherFindAnything = false;
def signatureMatcher = _1 =~ "(public |)([0-9a-zA-Z<>._,]*) ([a-zA-Z]*)(\\([^{]*\\))\\s*(throws [a-zA-Z0-9]+|)";
if (signatureMatcher.find()) {
    isSignatureMatcherFindAnything = true;
    result += '"';
    result += signatureMatcher[0][3].replaceAll('([A-Z])', '-$1').toLowerCase().replaceAll('^_', '');
}

def paramsMatcher = signatureMatcher[0][4] =~ "(@QueryParam)(\\(\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\"\\))";
if (paramsMatcher.find()) {
    result += '?'
    for (def i = 0; i < paramsMatcher.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            result += '&';
        }
        def param = paramsMatcher[i][3];
        result += param;
        result += '={';
        result += param;
        result += '}';
    }
}
result += '")'

def headersMatcher = _1 =~ "(\\@Consumes)(\\((\"|)([^\"\\)]+)(\"|)\\))";
if (headersMatcher.find()) {
    result += '\r\n@Headers(';
    def content = headersMatcher[0][4];
    if (content.contains('8')) {
        result += 'CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF_8';
    } else {
        result += 'CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON';
    }
    result += ')';
}

if (isSignatureMatcherFindAnything) {
    result += '\r\n'
    result += signatureMatcher[0][2];
    result += ' ';
    result += signatureMatcher[0][3];
    result += signatureMatcher[0][4].replaceAll("@QueryParam", "@Param");
    
    if (signatureMatcher[0].size() == 6) {
        result += ' ';
        result += signatureMatcher[0][5];
    }
    
    result += ';';
}

return result;
```

Полученный `Live template` работает следующим образом:

1. Копируем метод.
2. Запускаем `Live template` *(при помощи заданного ранее шортката)*.

Таким образом этот код:

```
/**
 * Finds all
 * @param id    the id
 * @param codes list of codes
 * @return entities
*/
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Entity> get(@QueryParam("id") Integer id, @QueryParam("barcodes") List<Long> codes) {
  return entityBean.findByIdAndCodes(id, codes);
}
```

превращается в следующее:

```
/**
 * Finds all
 * @param id    the id
 * @param codes list of codes
 * @return entities
*/
@RequestLine("GET " + PATH + "get")
List<Entity> get(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("codes") List<Long> codes);
```

Comment: Крутое решение! Чем больше присматриваюсь к идее, тем больше вижу там возможностей, о которых не знал